# DS18B20 not showing up Pi 400

Tags: gpio, ubuntu, ds18b20, pi-400

I have a raspberry pi 400 running ubuntu server.

- I have a DS18B20 with a 4.7k resistor connected from the power to the data wire.
- I boot up the pi and run the `sudo modprobe w1-gpio` and `sudo modprobe w1-therm` commands.
- I then go to the `/sys/bus/w1/devices/` directory and run `ls` and nothing shows up.
- I have added `dtoverlay=w1-gpio` to the boot config.txt.
- I have also tried using a new sensor and a new resistor and I am getting the same problem.

Comment: Does it work with Raspberry Pi OS?

Comment: Why would anyone want to run a server on Pi400?

Comment: @Milliways How is that relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Joan suggested me to try, Rasperry Pi OS was the solution. Thanks =)